# iOS and Mac - disable iCloud auto-update downloads / backup

Tags: ios, icloud

It seems that a huge chunk of the precious SSD on my Macbook Pro gets taken by iCloud updates or backup's. I have backup's disabled in iTunes, but this is somehow still automagically still downloading. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to **totally** disable iCloud, you can go in `System Settings`, and then click on `iCloud` and select `Disconnect`.

You won't be connected to iCloud anymore and thus, won't send updates or receive data.